# Ar.js problems with recognizing marker outdoors - contrast/brightness

Tags: html, gltf, ar.js

My 3d model AR is working perfectly indoors, but in direct sunlight outside it can not find the marker, which is a custom barcode number 5 (see image below). Is there a way to make the camera (which is accessed through google chrome on Android) perform better in bright outdoor conditions? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try to change the Threshold, but you haven't direct acces to this setting, this because Ar.js is based on jsartoolkit5 but is not implemented. If you are working on THREEx you can set in update the **setThreshold** level, supposed that you have an istance of **arToolkitSource**:

```js
arToolkitSource.init(function onReady(){

      console.log(arToolkitContext.arController);
        if( arToolkitContext.arController !== null ){
          arToolkitContext.arController.arToolkitSource.init(function onReady(){

           arToolkitContext.arController.setThreshold(value) 
          }
        }
    })
```

But this is not possible with the Aframe version, you can't access to the arController in the same way. It will be nice that this feature will be added to the library.